# How could you with jQuery select the number at the end of the pathline?

Tags: jquery, html, css-selectors

I am trying to grab that `15` at the end of the href with jquery..

```
 <a class="ajax" href="/organizations/1/media/galleries/15">Silly Gangs</a>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `jQuery` for this, just vanilla JavaScript:

```
var href = someLinkElement.href;
var lastIndex = href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1;
var lastComponent = href.substring(lastIndex);
```

Comment: Agreed that jQuery is overkill, until you have a list of these things that you want to work with ... then the `$(elements).each(...);` becomes really handy

Answer (score 2):

```
var num = $("a.ajax").attr("href").replace(/.*\/(\d+)$/, "$1");
```

Explanation of the regex:

```
.*           # anything (this runs right to the end of the string)
\/           # a slash (backtracks to the last slash in the string)
(\d+)        # multiple digits (will be saved to group $1)
$            # end-of-string anchor (ensures correct match)
```

The `replace()` call will substitute the entire input string with the number at its end, whatever it might be. It will return `""` if there's no number at the end.

Oh, and as added bonus here is something that uses jQuery some more, modify as needed:

```
$("a.ajax").each(function () {
  $(this).data("num", /* store in data for later re-use */
    $(this).attr("href").replace(/.*\/(\d+)$/, "$1")
  );
});
```

Comment: YOU ARE JEDI. That's now even a documented jQuery method and it works. How is not 'actually replacing anything'?

Comment: @Trip: `attr("href")` returns a string, basically a copy of the attribute value. The `replace()` operates on that copy. To replace the actual `href` value, I'd need to call `attr("href", newValue)`, but that's not happening here.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
var Value=$("a.ajax").attr("href").split("/").pop();
```

It's faster than using regex.

[Example in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/BNxFB/)

Comment: since it's a set of galleries I imagine there's going to be a lot of these at a time. Yours only grabs ONE of those. Just thought I would point that out. ~ Also, I like how we both managed to post roughly the same answer at the same time ;)

Comment: The OP didn't indicate that there were more than one. I.e. "I am trying to grab that `15` at the end of **the** href".

Comment: +1 for the `split()`/`pop()` approach. This is somewhat more resource-intensive than doing it with `lastIndexOf()`/`substring()`, but for most UI code this will hardly make any noticeable difference.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".ajax").each( function() {
  var lastElementOfHREF = $(this).attr("href").split("/").pop();
  // now you do something here with this lastElement...
});
```